# How to join rows which have common column values?

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

```
Index   Variable     Name
0         'var1'    'apple'
1         'var2'    'orange'
2         'var1'    'pineapple'
```

I would like to get this:

```
Index    Variable     Name
0         'var1'      ['apple','pineapple']
1         'var2'      ['orange']
```

I tried using `df.groupby(['Variable'])` but I do not know how to convert it back into a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `list` function on the grouped object for the aggregation, this turns the `Name` Series object in each group to a list and treat it as a single element in the result:

```
df.groupby("Variable").Name.apply(list).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: You got there before I did! Would it be possible for you to post the explanation behind the code as well? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if instead of having 'Name' as my column name, I have 'Fruit Name'?

Comment: You can use bracket to access the column. `df.groupby("Variable")['Fruit Name'].apply(list).reset_index()`

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your help!